# Display Keyboard integration

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, raspberry-pi

for a project I have built on a Tkinter based GUI, I would like to run it on a touch display.

Does anyone know a way or a way to have an on-screen keyboard, that is installed on a Raspberry Pi, that open up when an input field is clicked in the gui ?

I would be very grateful for any input

Comment: Your question is very broad and hard to understand. What have you tried so far? Usually you can use a GUI as is on a raspberry with a touchscreen display. If you want to enter text, you need an on-screen keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to do some correction regarding the spacing in the code
because StackOverFlow, doesn't support pasting the code "Wide".

Here is total code for on-screen Keyboard using tkinter model in python :-

```
from tkinter import *
import ttkthemes as td
from tkinter import ttk


def select(value):
    if value == 'Space':
        textarea.insert(INSERT, ' ')

    elif value == 'Enter':
        textarea.insert(INSERT, '\n')

    elif value == 'Tab':
        textarea.insert(INSERT, '\t')

    elif value == 'Del':
        textarea.delete(1.0, END)

    elif value == 'Backs':
        i = textarea.get(1.0, END)
        newtext = i[:-2]

        textarea.delete(1.0, END)
        textarea.insert(INSERT, newtext)

    elif value == 'Shift ↑':
        varRow = 2
        varColumn = 0

        for button in leftShiftButtons:

            command = lambda x=button: select(x)
            if button != 'Space':
                ttk.Button(root, text=button, command=command, width=10, 
                ).grid(row=varRow, column=varColumn)

            varColumn += 1
            if varColumn > 14:
                varColumn = 0
                varRow += 1

    elif value == '↑ Shift':
        varRow = 2
        varColumn = 0

        for button in buttons:

            command = lambda x=button: select(x)
            if button != 'Space':
                ttk.Button(root, text=button, command=command, width=10, 
                ).grid(row=varRow, column=varColumn)

            varColumn += 1
            if varColumn > 14:
                varColumn = 0
                varRow += 1

    elif value == 'Caps':

        varRow = 2
        varColumn = 0

        for button in capsButtons:

            command = lambda x=button: select(x)
            if button != 'Space':
                ttk.Button(root, text=button, command=command, width=10, 
                ).grid(row=varRow, column=varColumn)

            varColumn += 1
            if varColumn > 14:
                varColumn = 0
                varRow += 1

    elif value == 'CAPS':

        varRow = 2
        varColumn = 0

        for button in buttons:

            command = lambda x=button: select(x)
            if button != 'Space':
                ttk.Button(root, text=button, command=command, width=10, 
                ).grid(row=varRow, column=varColumn)

            varColumn += 1
            if varColumn > 14:
                varColumn = 0
                varRow += 1


    else:
        textarea.insert(INSERT, value)

    textarea.focus_set()


root = td.ThemedTk()
root.get_themes()
root.set_theme('aquativo')
root.title('On-Screen Keyboard created by Faizan Khan')
root.config(bg='whitesmoke')
root.resizable(0, 0)

titleLabel = Label(root, text='On-Screen Keyboard', font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), 
             bg='whitesmoke', fg='gray30')
titleLabel.grid(row=0, columnspan=15)

textarea = Text(root, font=('arial', 15, 'bold'), height=10, width=100, 
           wrap='word',bd=8,relief=SUNKEN)
textarea.grid(row=1, columnspan=15)
textarea.focus_set()

buttons = ['`', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '-', '=', 
          'Backs', 'Del',
           'Tab', 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', '[', '7', 
            '8', '9',
           'Caps', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', ';', 'Enter', 
           '4', '5', '6',
           'Shift ↑', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', ',', '.', '/', '↑ 
            Shift', '1', '2', '3',
            'Space']

leftShiftButtons = ['~', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', 
                   '+', 'Backs', 'Del',
                    'Tab', 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 
                     ']', '7', '8', '9',
                    'Caps', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', ':', 
                    'Enter', '4', '5', '6',
                    'Shift ↑', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', '<', '>', '?', 
                    '↑ Shift', '1', '2', '3',
                    'Space'

                    ]

capsButtons = ['`', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '-', '=', 
             'Backs', 'Del',
               'Tab', 'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P', '[', 
               '7', '8', '9',
               'CAPS', 'A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', ';', 
                'Enter', '4', '5', '6',
               'Shift ↑', 'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M', ',', '.', '/', '↑ 
                Shift', '1', '2', '3',
               'Space']

varRow = 2
varColumn = 0

for button in buttons:

    command = lambda x=button: select(x)
    if button != 'Space':
        ttk.Button(root, text=button, command=command, width=10 
        ).grid(row=varRow, column=varColumn)

    if button == 'Space':
        ttk.Button(root, text=button, command=command, width=30, ).grid(row=6, 
        column=0, columnspan=14)

    varColumn += 1
    if varColumn > 14:
        varColumn = 0
        varRow += 1

root.mainloop()
```